# Simple java recursion, unpredictable program behavior

Tags: java, recursion

Trivial program to calculate compound interest, I = P(1+n)^y.

```
public class Interest {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        double sum = calculate(1000,10,3);
        System.out.println(sum);
        //sanity check, using non-recursive formula:
        double amt = 1000*(Math.pow(1 + 0.1, 3));
        System.out.println(amt);


    }

    public static double calculate(double initialAmount, double interest, int years){

        double yearly = initialAmount + initialAmount*(interest/100);

        System.out.println("calculate is called with P = " + initialAmount + ", interest = "+interest+", and years = " + years);
        System.out.println("This year's amount: "+yearly);

        if (years <= 0){
            return initialAmount;
        }
        if (years == 1){
            return yearly;
        }
        else {
            return yearly + calculate(yearly, interest, years - 1);
        }

    }

    }
```

The output is as follows (notice that YEARLY is calculated correctly but not returned as expected):

```
debug:
calculate is called with P = 1000.0, interest = 10.0, and years = 3
This year's amount: 1100.0
calculate is called with P = 1100.0, interest = 10.0, and years = 2
This year's amount: 1210.0
calculate is called with P = 1210.0, interest = 10.0, and years = 1
This year's amount: 1331.0
3641.0
1331.0000000000005
```

When I debug, execution enters if (years == 1) as expected, but then *also* enters the following else block. How can it enter both branches? Please advise; I've been racking my brains, and restarting the computer and NetBeans didn't help.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the `else` is in one recursive depth ABOVE. please check the `years` variable. It should be `2` if you are in the `else` block.

Comment: Why not just use Math.pow?

Comment: @AndyTurner since this is most likely an exercise on recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `else` branch is entered on any call where `years > 1`, especially for `years == 2`. Form there, you call `calculate` with `years == 1`, which is when you enter the `if`-statement in question. Now after the `return` in this `if`-statement is executed, execution resumes on the previous level of the recursion where it stopped. This is within the `else` block, after the recursive call. When you check the value of `years`, you will see that it changes from `1` to `2` after the `return` in the `if` is executed.

Comment: I see now how it could enter both branches. It seems there's much I have yet to learn about recursion. Many thanks!

Comment: By "enter both branches" in my comment above I mean "appear to enter"  as I'm watching execution in debugger (as Janos pointed out below). I drew a diagram of calls and returns, and it really helped. Great explanation, Turing.

Answer (score 1):

You're not entering the else block after the years==1 if block, you're simply adding yearly to every recursive call.

Change the return statement in the else block to

```
return calculate(yearly, interest, years - 1)
```

from

```
return yearly + calculate(yearly, interest, years - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, Taelsin! That totally worked. I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

No, execution does not enter the else block after that if block. That's impossible. If it appears that way, then it seems you are misunderstanding your debugger. Note that after the terminal if, execution will be stepping back through the else statements in the preceding stacks. But it will not enter. Only step back into.

The result is accumulated in the first parameter, there's no need to add the value of yearly on the last line of your method. The logic can also be a bit simplified:

```
    if (years == 1){
        return yearly;
    }
    return calculate(yearly, interest, years - 1);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10196972)

Comment: @msrd0 Why do you think that? The OP asks how it's possible to enter the `else` block after the `if`. I explain that he's misinterpreting the situation, no, execution does not enter the `else` block after the `if`, contrary to what OP *believes*. Then I provide a correction to his broken algorithm. Am I missing something?